# What might be causing this error: No rule to make target /usr/local/lib/liblua5.1.dylib}

Tags: c++, cmake, lua, homebrew

Whats up?

What might be causing this error while trying to compile?:

Ps: I am using MacOS Monterey.

[ 99%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/otclient.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]:  **No rule to make target /usr/local/lib/liblua5.1.dylib}'**, needed by bin/otclient'.  Stop.
make[1]:  [src/CMakeFiles/otclient.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Here is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
project(otclient)

# *****************************************************************************
# Options
# *****************************************************************************
option(FRAMEWORK_SOUND "Use SOUND " ON)
option(FRAMEWORK_XML "Use XML " ON)
option(FRAMEWORK_NET "Use NET " ON)
option(FRAMEWORK_SQL "Use SQL" OFF)
option(TOOGLE_DIRECTX "Use DX9 support" OFF)

# *****************************************************************************
# Cmake Features
# *****************************************************************************
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# Make will print more details
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF)

# Generate compile_commands.json
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

# Define Framework Options for use in compilation
set(FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS "")
if (FRAMEWORK_SOUND)
    set(FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS ${FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS} -DFRAMEWORK_SOUND)
endif()
if (FRAMEWORK_XML)
    set(FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS ${FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS} -DFRAMEWORK_XML)
endif()
if (FRAMEWORK_NET)
    set(FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS ${FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS} -DFRAMEWORK_NET)
endif()

set(VERSION "1.0.0")

# *****************************************************************************
# Client
# *****************************************************************************
if (MSVC)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "" ../cmake/icon/otcicon.rc)
else()
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "")
endif()

add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501)
add_definitions(${FRAMEWORK_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions(-D"VERSION=\\"${VERSION}\\"")

# *****************************************************************************
# Packages / Libs
# *****************************************************************************
find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS system thread filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL QUIET)
find_package(PhysFS REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(LibLZMA REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)
find_package(Lua REQUIRED)
# OpenGL/GLEW = 
## TODO: CMake Documentation says that this is not the right
# Thing for Mac OS X, but it works for now.
if(APPLE)
    include_directories(/usr/X11R6/include/)
    link_directories(/usr/X11R6/lib/)
    SET(OPENGL_LIBRARIES GL)
else()
    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
endif()
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
if (WIN32)
    find_package(DbgHelp REQUIRED)
endif(WIN32)
if(NOT OPENSSL_FOUND)
    find_package(GMP REQUIRED)
endif()
if(TOOGLE_DIRECTX)
    find_package(DirectX REQUIRED)
endif()
if(FRAMEWORK_SOUND)
    find_package(OpenAL REQUIRED)
    find_package(VorbisFile REQUIRED)
    find_package(Vorbis REQUIRED)
    find_package(Ogg REQUIRED)
endif()
if(FRAMEWORK_SQL)
    find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)
endif()

# *****************************************************************************
# OTClient source files configuration
# *****************************************************************************
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    client/animatedtext.cpp
    client/animator.cpp
    client/spriteappearances.cpp
    client/client.cpp
    client/container.cpp
    client/creature.cpp
    client/creatures.cpp
    client/effect.cpp
    client/game.cpp
    client/houses.cpp
    client/item.cpp
    client/itemtype.cpp
    client/lightview.cpp
    client/localplayer.cpp
    client/luafunctions.cpp
    client/luavaluecasts.cpp
    client/map.cpp
    client/mapio.cpp
    client/mapview.cpp
    client/minimap.cpp
    client/missile.cpp
    client/outfit.cpp
    client/player.cpp
    client/protocolcodes.cpp
    client/protocolgame.cpp
    client/protocolgameparse.cpp
    client/protocolgamesend.cpp
    client/shadermanager.cpp
    client/spritemanager.cpp
    client/statictext.cpp
    client/thing.cpp
    client/thingtype.cpp
    client/thingtypemanager.cpp
    client/tile.cpp
    client/towns.cpp
    client/uicreature.cpp
    client/uiitem.cpp
    client/uimap.cpp
    client/uimapanchorlayout.cpp
    client/uiminimap.cpp
    client/uiprogressrect.cpp
    client/uisprite.cpp
    framework/core/adaptativeframecounter.cpp
    framework/core/application.cpp
    framework/core/asyncdispatcher.cpp
    framework/core/binarytree.cpp
    framework/core/clock.cpp
    framework/core/config.cpp
    framework/core/configmanager.cpp
    framework/core/event.cpp
    framework/core/eventdispatcher.cpp
    framework/core/filestream.cpp
    framework/core/graphicalapplication.cpp
    framework/core/logger.cpp
    framework/core/module.cpp
    framework/core/modulemanager.cpp
    framework/core/resourcemanager.cpp
    framework/core/scheduledevent.cpp
    framework/core/timer.cpp
    framework/graphics/animatedtexture.cpp
    framework/graphics/apngloader.cpp
    framework/graphics/bitmapfont.cpp
    framework/graphics/cachedtext.cpp
    framework/graphics/coordsbuffer.cpp
    framework/graphics/drawpool.cpp
    framework/graphics/fontmanager.cpp
    framework/graphics/framebuffer.cpp
    framework/graphics/framebuffermanager.cpp
    framework/graphics/graphics.cpp
    framework/graphics/image.cpp
    framework/graphics/ogl/painterogl.cpp
    framework/graphics/ogl/painterogl1.cpp
    framework/graphics/ogl/painterogl2.cpp
    framework/graphics/painter.cpp
    framework/graphics/paintershaderprogram.cpp
    framework/graphics/particle.cpp
    framework/graphics/particleaffector.cpp
    framework/graphics/particleeffect.cpp
    framework/graphics/particleemitter.cpp
    framework/graphics/particlemanager.cpp
    framework/graphics/particlesystem.cpp
    framework/graphics/particletype.cpp
    framework/graphics/pool.cpp
    framework/graphics/shader.cpp
    framework/graphics/shaderprogram.cpp
    framework/graphics/texture.cpp
    framework/graphics/texturemanager.cpp
    framework/input/mouse.cpp
    framework/luaengine/lbitlib.cpp
    framework/luaengine/luaexception.cpp
    framework/luaengine/luainterface.cpp
    framework/luaengine/luaobject.cpp
    framework/luaengine/luavaluecasts.cpp
    framework/luafunctions.cpp
    framework/net/connection.cpp
    framework/net/inputmessage.cpp
    framework/net/outputmessage.cpp
    framework/net/protocol.cpp
    framework/net/protocolhttp.cpp
    framework/net/server.cpp
    framework/otml//otmldocument.cpp
    framework/otml//otmlemitter.cpp
    framework/otml//otmlexception.cpp
    framework/otml//otmlnode.cpp
    framework/otml//otmlparser.cpp
    framework/platform/platform.cpp
    framework/platform/platformwindow.cpp
    framework/platform/unixcrashhandler.cpp
    framework/platform/unixplatform.cpp
    framework/platform/win32crashhandler.cpp
    framework/platform/win32platform.cpp
    framework/platform/win32window.cpp
    framework/platform/x11window.cpp
    framework/sound/combinedsoundsource.cpp
    framework/sound/oggsoundfile.cpp
    framework/sound/soundbuffer.cpp
    framework/sound/soundchannel.cpp
    framework/sound/soundfile.cpp
    framework/sound/soundmanager.cpp
    framework/sound/soundsource.cpp
    framework/sound/streamsoundsource.cpp
    framework/stdext/demangle.cpp
    framework/stdext/math.cpp
    framework/stdext/net.cpp
    framework/stdext/string.cpp
    framework/stdext/time.cpp
    framework/ui/uianchorlayout.cpp
    framework/ui/uiboxlayout.cpp
    framework/ui/uigridlayout.cpp
    framework/ui/uihorizontallayout.cpp
    framework/ui/uilayout.cpp
    framework/ui/uimanager.cpp
    framework/ui/uiparticles.cpp
    framework/ui/uitextedit.cpp
    framework/ui/uitranslator.cpp
    framework/ui/uiverticallayout.cpp
    framework/ui/uiwidget.cpp
    framework/ui/uiwidgetbasestyle.cpp
    framework/ui/uiwidgetimage.cpp
    framework/ui/uiwidgettext.cpp
    framework/util/color.cpp
    framework/util/crypt.cpp
    framework/xml/tinystr.cpp
    framework/xml/tinyxml.cpp
    framework/xml/tinyxmlerror.cpp
    framework/xml/tinyxmlparser.cpp
    protobuf/appearances.pb.cc
    main.cpp
)

# *****************************************************************************
# Includes and librarys
# *****************************************************************************
if(MSVC)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
        ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${LUAJIT_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${VORBISFILE_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${GMP_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${PHYSFS_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${NLOHMANN_JSON_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${MYSQL_CLIENT_LIBS}
        ${LUAJIT_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
        ${PHYSFS_LIBRARY}
        ${ZLIB_LIBRARY}
        ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}
        ${LIBLZMA_LIBRARIES}
        ${NLOHMANN_JSON_LIBRARY}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        ${DirectX_LIBRARY}
        ${DirectX_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENAL_LIBRARY}
        ${VORBISFILE_LIBRARY}
        ${VORBIS_LIBRARY}
        ${OGG_LIBRARY}
        ${MYSQL_LIBRARY}
        ${GMP_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
        ${DBGHELP_LIBRARY}

        GLEW::GLEW
    )
    
else()
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
        ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${VORBISFILE_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${GMP_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${PHYSFS_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${NLOHMANN_JSON_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${LUA_LIBRARY}}
        ${PHYSFS_LIBRARY}
        ${ZLIB_LIBRARY}
        ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}
        ${LIBLZMA_LIBRARIES}
        ${NLOHMANN_JSON_LIBRARY}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        ${DirectX_LIBRARY}
        ${DirectX_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENAL_LIBRARY}
        ${VORBISFILE_LIBRARY}
        ${VORBIS_LIBRARY}
        ${OGG_LIBRARY}
        ${MYSQL_LIBRARY}
        ${GMP_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}

        Boost::boost
        Boost::filesystem
        Boost::system
        Threads::Threads
    )
endif()

# *****************************************************************************
# Enable otclient console only for debug build
# *****************************************************************************
if(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE"
        LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup"
        LINK_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup"
        LINK_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup"
    )
endif(WIN32)

# *****************************************************************************
# Link compilation files to the "build/release/bin" folder
# *****************************************************************************
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

**EDIT:**

Makefile generated by cmake:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.22

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/bin/cmake -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/mpgmateus/Downloads/otclient-rework-cmake

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /Users/mpgmateus/Downloads/otclient-rework-cmake/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/bin/ccmake -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /Users/mpgmateus/Downloads/otclient-rework-cmake/build/CMakeFiles /Users/mpgmateus/Downloads/otclient-rework-cmake/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /Users/mpgmateus/Downloads/otclient-rework-cmake/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named protobuf

# Build rule for target.
protobuf: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 protobuf
.PHONY : protobuf

# fast build rule for target.
protobuf/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f src/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/build.make src/protobuf/CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/build
.PHONY : protobuf/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named otclient

# Build rule for target.
otclient: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 otclient
.PHONY : otclient

# fast build rule for target.
otclient/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f src/CMakeFiles/otclient.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/otclient.dir/build
.PHONY : otclient/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... otclient"
    @echo "... protobuf"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

I will be very grateful for your help ;)

Thanks!

Comment: You have forgotten the *minimal* part of your [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason, is that the include of the library has an extra "}".

[image]

Comment: Never ever post images of text! And please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).